# How to define whether picklist of entity attribute global or local?

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics

Dynamics 365, web-api (front-end).

How to know the type of Picklist (local or global) which is used by entity attribute? I.e. picklist cab be global or local. I expected attribute metadata contains info about it (for example IsGlobalPickList property) but I see nothing. I wouldn't like to send two request for global and local variants each time...

Comment: Check this - https://stackoverflow.com/q/51591182/7920473